# jquery add class to element when radio button is checked

Tags: jquery, onchange, addclass

I am trying to add the class "disabled" to an element when a certain radio button in a list of radio buttons is checked.

Here is my (simplified) html

```
<div id="input_layout" class="image ui-buttonset">

<div class="customizer-subtitle"></div>
    <input id="layout0" class="image-select ui-helper-hidden-accessible" type="radio" data-customize-setting-link="layout" name="_customize-radio-layout" value="0"></input>
    <input id="layout1" class="image-select ui-helper-hidden-accessible" type="radio" checked="checked" data-customize-setting-link="layout" name="_customize-radio-layout" value="1"></input>
    <input id="layout2" class="image-select ui-helper-hidden-accessible" type="radio" data-customize-setting-link="layout" name="_customize-radio-layout" value="2"></input>
    <input id="layout3" class="image-select ui-helper-hidden-accessible" type="radio" data-customize-setting-link="layout" name="_customize-radio-layout" value="3"></input>
    <input id="layout4" class="image-select ui-helper-hidden-accessible" type="radio" data-customize-setting-link="layout" name="_customize-radio-layout" value="4"></input>

</div>
```

And here is the jquery I have written:

```
$("#input_layout input").change(function() {
var layout_selection = $('#input_layout input[class="image-select"]:checked').val();
    if (layout_selection == '1') {
    $('#customize-control-site_style').addClass('disabled');
  }
});
```

In this instance, I am trying to add the class 'disabled' to #customize-control-site_style. At present this does not work at all though.

Comment: Your value is saved inside the variable `layout_selection` but check `navbar_pos_val`. Is that normal?

Comment: Ah yes, sorry typo, ammended in description

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should attach the event to the radio buttons class, then use `this`

```
$("input.image-select:radio").change(function() {
    if (this.value == "1") {
        $('#customize-control-site_style').addClass('disabled');
    } else {
        $('#customize-control-site_style').removeClass('disabled');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$("input.image-select:radio").click(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        $('#customize-control-site_style').addClass('disabled');
    }
    else $('#customize-control-site_style').removeClass('disabled');
});
```